# Convert string format Date(1528822800000) to date

Tags: javascript, date

I have a date format as follows:

> var myDateString = "Date (1528822800000)"

1. I do not know what to call it with the name?
2. How can I convert it to date in javascript?

I tried using

> Date (myDateString)

but the type that it returns is string rather than date.
I also tried

> Date.parse (myDateString)

but it did not work.

How to convert **Date (1528822800000)** to date in javascript? (not use Moment.js)

Comment: `new Date (1528822800000)` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: This is a duplicate, but hard to find good answers.

Comment: Sorry for that, but I do not know the keyword to search because I do not know what to call with the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Unix time :

From [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) :

> Unix time passed 1,000,000,000 seconds in 2001-09-09T01:46:40Z. It was
>   celebrated in Copenhagen, Denmark at a party held by DKUUG (at
>   03:46:40 local time). Unix time (also known as POSIX time[citation
>   needed] or UNIX Epoch time[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)) is a system for describing a point in
>   time, defined as the number of seconds that have elapsed since
>   00:00:00 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), Thursday, 1 January
>   1970,[2].

```js
var time = "Date (1528822800000)";
var unixtime = time.replace(/\D/g,'');

var date = new Date(Number(unixtime));

console.log(date);
```

Comment: My string is: "Date (1528822800000)"
So I'll have to peel to get the numbers in brackets?

Comment: @TranAudi yes . Try var date = new Date(Number("1528822800000"));

Comment: I'm looking to use regex to get numbers in parentheses :)

Comment: Yes. it worked!
You answered both of my questions,
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

1. It's called UNIX epoch time

You can convert it into Human date through this website

https://www.epochconverter.com/

For more information, you can read what is epoch time from that website too ("What is epoch time?")

Normally, the length is 10 if it is in seconds and 13 it is in milliseconds (*1000)

2. You can create date objects with new Date().

For example:

```
var d = new Date(milliseconds);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var myDateString = "Date (1528822800000)"
var time = myDateString.match(/([\d]+)/)
var date = new Date(parseInt(time[0]))
console.log(date.toISOString())
```

`2018-06-12T17:00:00.000Z`

Comment: The regular expression can be just `/\d+/`, but consider `.replace(/\D/g,'')` instead of *match*. ;-)